# Using jQuery to change nav colour is causing mixed results

Tags: jquery, css, header, nav

I wrote some jQuery code that changes the colour of my nav/header based on what section of my web page it is on. It works but not perfectly, sometimes it changes mid section when its not suppose to, or changes to the wrong colour a the wrong section.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


var top1 = $('#home').offset().top;
var top2 = $('#featuredWork').offset().top - headerHeight;
var top3 = $('#caseStudy').offset().top - headerHeight;
var top4 = $('#about').offset().top - headerHeight;
var top5 = $('#contact').offset().top - headerHeight;

//Change colour of header bar and elements based on which section the user is on
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top1 && $(document).scrollTop() < top2) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top2 && $(document).scrollTop() < top3) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#21303f');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#dadfe0');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top3 && $(document).scrollTop() < top4) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top4 && $(document).scrollTop() < top5) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#21303f');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#dadfe0');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top5) {
    $('#header').css('background-color', '#dadfe0');
    $('.nav').css('color', '#21303f');
  }  
});

});
```

Here is my uncompleted portfolio website where this error is occurring, sometimes it works when the page loads, other times not so

[enter link description here](http://kylebinger.com)

If anyone could give me some insight into why this isnt perfectly working every time that would be great

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you need to take into account the height of each section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way of testing this for you but my suspicion is that this has to do with saving the offsets in variables. 
By doing this:

```
var top1 = $('#home').offset().top;
```

The value is stored in `top1`, but this doesn't set a reference, therefore this variable will not get updated whenever the offset changes.

Currently you are using `$(document).ready(function() { });` but this only implies that the code inside it will not be executed until the DOM is loaded (your HTML). It doesn't wait for images to be loaded. As you can imagine, the offset will change when images are loaded, rendering the value in `top1` invalid. I suspect you are getting mixed results because sometimes document ready happens to execute after images have been loaded (and it will appear to be working) and sometimes it gets executed before images get loaded (and it will appear not to be working).

A solution would be to get the offsets directly inside your document scroll function instead of using stored variables. (or you could save your variables inside your document scroll function) E.g. this

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= top1 && $(document).scrollTop() < top2)
```

would become this

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#home').offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() < ($('#featuredWork').offset().top - headerHeight))
```

One more thing you could do is change from `document ready` to `window load`. The window load function will wait for images to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks so much this seems to have done the trick, haven't had another problem with it since i implemented your solution.